# "identity expired" occurred at invoke chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

On hyperledger-facric:1.4.1 with the following configuration.

```
$ sudo docker stack services hlstack
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                              PORTS
4269ka27vrd3        hlstack_peer0       replicated          1/1                 hyperledger/fabric-peer:1.4.1      *:7051->7051/tcp
6ki20vksghqx        hlstack_ca          replicated          1/1                 hyperledger/fabric-ca:1.4.1        *:7054->7054/tcp
7xq36biwph83        hlstack_cli         replicated          1/1                 hyperledger/fabric-tools:1.4.1
kfpkai1ahaww        hlstack_peer2       replicated          1/1                 hyperledger/fabric-peer:1.4.1      *:27051->7051/tcp
rnqm2ilsvgfb        hlstack_orderer     replicated          1/1                 hyperledger/fabric-orderer:1.4.1   *:7050->7050/tcp
rnt1tfivcmus        hlstack_peer1       replicated          1/1                 hyperledger/fabric-peer:1.4.1      *:17051->7051/tcp
```

After one peer is elected leader, failed invoke chaincode.

```
2020-08-29 04:49:12.804 UTC [gossip.election] beLeader -> INFO 02d b02622144c4911f2ff06f0a4a37f7a161126e2e16eb529e6eac0657c0be483a1 : Becoming a leader
2020-08-29 04:49:12.804 UTC [gossip.service] func1 -> INFO 02e Elected as a leader, starting delivery service for channel mychannel
2020-08-29 05:03:20.810 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 02f unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=10.255.0.3:57852 error="identity expired" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=1.399845ms
2020-08-29 05:03:22.616 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 030 unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=10.255.0.3:57864 error="identity expired" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=481.93μs
```

Please teach us how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the logs, the problem is occurred due to X.509 certificate expiration.

To solve this problem you can reenroll an expired identity or modify an identity.

You can find details on [Hyperledger Fabric CA](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/) documentation.

You can find the command reference on following link.
https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/clientcli.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll check the links.